# My for-loop is iterating by two

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that counts the number of vowels in a sentence, but for some reason my for-loop keeps iterating by 2 (figured this out by printing out the value of i during each iteration). What's wrong with it?

```
 //input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sentence;
    //prompt
    System.out.print("Type a sentence. \nThe number of vowels will be counted.");
    sentence = input.nextLine();
    //vowel check
    int charcount = 0;
    String temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
    {
      temp = sentence.substring(i, i++);
      if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("a") == true) 
        charcount ++;
      else if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("e") == true) 
        charcount ++;
      else if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("i") == true) 
        charcount ++;
      else if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("o") == true) 
        charcount ++;
      else if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("u") == true) 
        charcount ++;

      }

     System.out.print("There are " + charcount + " vowels in your sentence.");
}
}
```

Comment: `i, i++`??? That's going to have an effect

Comment: I won't add an answer because there are two that are already correct. What you have to understand is that i++ is actually telling the program to read that variable, then increment it by one. So, change the line temp = sentence.substring(i, i++) to temp = sentence.substring(i, i+1). That should do it.

Comment: suppose you should change the line `temp = sentence.substring(i, i+1); to this.`

Comment: You probably should just replace `substring()` with `charAt(i)` it returns the character (as a `char`) and is clearer as to the intent.

Comment: `for (char temp: sentence.toCharArray()) if ("AEIOUaeiou".indexOf(temp) != -1) charcount++;` is another way of doing this.

Answer (score 5):

There are two times when you're incrementing `i` , once in your for loop definition, and once in your `sentence.substring`

Any time you put `i++` the variable `i` will be increased by 1, regardless of it being in the for loop's definition or in another part of the loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
{
      temp = sentence.substring(i, i+1);
      if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("a") == true) 
        charcount ++;
      else if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("e") == true) 
        charcount ++;
      else if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("i") == true) 
        charcount ++;
      else if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("o") == true) 
        charcount ++;
      else if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("u") == true) 
        charcount ++;

}
```

Should work.

Also, and someone who is more familiar with java than I am can correct me on this if I'm mistaken, but `temp.equalsIgnoreCase()` returns a boolean, so you don't need to do `== True`, you can just write `else if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("u"))`

Addition: As per `Scary Wombat`'s comment, you could simplify this even more so, as so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
{
      temp = sentence.substring(i, i+1);
      if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("a") || temp.equalsIgnoreCase("e") ||
          temp.equalsIgnoreCase("i") || temp.equalsIgnoreCase("o") ||
          temp.equalsIgnoreCase("u")) 
             charcount ++;
}
```

Comment: yes `== true` is not necessary, but can be kept if it makes it easier to read for you.

Comment: Also suggest that you change the multiple `else if`s to `if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("a")  || temp.equalsIgnoreCase("e") || ...`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Noted and added to the post :) Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Change this line to:

```
temp = sentence.substring(i, i+1);
```

If you do `i++` it will increment the value of `i`.

i++ is equivalent to `i = i + 1`;

Comment: I do see what you are getting at, but `i++` is **not** equivalent to `i = i + 1`. The following is valid `sentence.substring(i, i = i+1)` and is equivalent to `++i`

Answer (score 1):

You have two instances of i++. Each is equivalent to i=i+1. You probably want your second one to be (i+1) rather than i++.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you don't use the `substring` method as it creates a new string from the original string.

**From the documentation:**

```
String  substring(int beginIndex)
Returns a new string that is a substring of this string.
```

Instead, use the `charAt` method which returns the character value at the specified index.

You can also cleanup the implementation by using a `string` with the vowels and invoking the `indexOf` method on it to test if the character in question is a vowel or not. Below is an example:

```
String vowels = "aeiou";

sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();
for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
    char letter = sentence.charAt(i);

    if (vowels.indexOf(letter) > -1) {
        charCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how the indexOf() method works in this situation?

Comment: @LFTY The method returns the index within the string for the first occurrence of the specified substring. In the above example, if you're searching for the letter `o`, it will return an index value representing the position of the first occurrence for that particular letter. An index of -1 means there was no match.